# Xamarin Forms How to call an async method

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an async method like so:

```
public async Task<LoginClass> LoginAsync(string email, string password)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
            });

            var response = await client.PostAsync(string.Format("/api/v1/login"), content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            LoginClass items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginClass>(responseString);

            return items;

        }
```

But when I call it in another method like so, its like my app freezes:

```
WebServiceClass webService = new WebServiceClass();

        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            
        }

        protected async void OnLogin(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Task<LoginClass> response = webService.LoginAsync(Email.Text, Password.Text);

            if(response.Result.error != null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", response.Result.error, "OK");
            }

        }
```

I put a break point on this line:

```
Task<LoginClass> response = webService.LoginAsync(Email.Text, Password.Text);
```

The break points, but after that nothing, it does not goto the next line. Its like its waiting for something.

What am I doing wrong and how do I properly call an async method?

Comment: Ummmm.....is there away to make it run faster?

Comment: When I run the URL of the api and it loads up in no time.....when I call the API from my app, its super slow

Comment: I am checking the URL from the browser

Comment: On my desktoppp

Comment: `response.Result` whever you found the idea to do that was completly wrong. await the call

Comment: Well, as Michael points out, you aren’t awaiting the call.  I completely missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the classic ***deadlock*** problem

So,

Never ever *ever* ***ever*** ***EVER*** ***E̓̀̑ͨ̑͐̐͐̽̐̌ͥṼ͑ͭͬ̋̏̈̓Eͮ͑́ͤ̆̅͆̌͋͊͌̽ͯͪ͒ͥ̀R̃̑̎ͩͪ̓Rͥ̐ͯ̾̇Ȑͥ̃̈̐ͣ̈̐ͨ͑̆͋̍R͆ͬ͗ͥ̈́̈́̄ͯ͑̽̓͆ͥ̉ͨR͌͂ͭ̑̎̍͐͂͗ͪ̔͛ͤ*** call `Result`, `Wait` or otherwise *block* on an *async* method (unless you completely understand what you are doing), In fact, just don't do it, there is ***always*** a better approach.  `await` them instead.

Your code should look like this

```
var response = await webService.LoginAsync(Email.Text, Password.Text);

if(response.error != null)
```

---

**Further reading**

[Stephen Cleary - Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: I know you think you're being cute, but please don't put images in posts that don't add anything constructive. Not all of us have unlimited data caps, nor high speed connections, and you're just wasting our bandwidth with pointless stuff like that. It's unprofessional (as is, frankly, the typographical scribble you've also insisted on including). (Not that you should ever have even posted an answer to such an obvious duplicate, but...whatever...)